# Solve mistyped text

Tags: support, suggested-edits, limits

Sometimes I come across some texts with a few mistakes in typing, something like 2 or 3 characters, that I can't correct, specially because is mandatory to fix at least 6 characters and I don't want to add more content to arrive at the missing characters. What I can do to fix the content ? There is not a mistyped edit mode?

Comment: You **sure** there's nothing else to improve in the post? I mean come on! It's just 6 chars!

Comment: Normally the problem is in a code source example and you don't need to add nothing, only to change in a way that the code works in a copy-paste mode

Comment: Editing code is its own can of worms. If it's your own post, though, you should be able to make any edit you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making such edits of **that** length is too minor to be considered a proper edit.

I mean, in the Suggested Edits queue, there is a reject reason for being too minor/not helping to improve the quality and readability of the post. 2 or 3 chars are probably too little for a proper edit. Good edits help much more than that, and I can't explain it better than the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

If the edit is really, really important, try finding other stuff to edit, like maybe changing a few words or doing a retag to help out. Just as a reminder, the six char limit ***only applies to those who do not have the privilege to instantly edit posts.*** So you might bypass it by earning the privilege, but seriously, don't make trival, super short edits, please.

Comment: ok, I got the idea

Comment: Remember to click the check mark when you have found the right answer...